# signalR performance game data refreshing in real time

Tags: c#, .net, performance, signalr, duplex

I heard of SignalR library which provide duplex communication in .NET .
I want to develop some game (in web browser), let's say 2 users move their points on canvas in real time. Both players need to have refreshed canvas as fast as possible. Would signalR handle it?

I read few topics on the internet where people hate it because of low performance. I'd like try it if it would handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to stay with .net Stack, then SignalR would be one of your main choices and if you want to make it faster use OWIN self-host app rather than  ordinary web app which needs to be hosted on IIS. So, you can remove tons of overheads.
Here you can find a tutorial on how to implement self-host SignalR:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Otherwise, if you can choose you're tech stack I'd suggest using [SocketIO](http://socket.io) which is faster (in most of the senarios) and is a full-stack (NodeJs and Browser) javascript library.

Here you can find a comparison between these 2 techs :

http://stevendavistechnotes.blogspot.com.au/2016/05/comparison-signalr-vs-socketio.html